# Call function from dictionary by name in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Let's say I have an interface with several functions:

```
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

interface MyFunctions {
  func1: () => string;
  func2: () => number;
  func3: (value: string) => string;
}
```

Now I want to get this functions by name:

```
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

type FuncNames = keyof MyFunctions;

function getFunc<T extends FuncNames>(key: T): MyFunctions[T] {
  return myFuncInstance[key]; // Imagine I have instance coming from somewhere.
}
```

And this actually works fully typesafe:

```
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

const a = getFunc('func1')(); // a - string;
const b = getFunc('func2')(); // b - number;
const c = getFunc('func3')('some'); // c - string;
```

And now I want to make one more step and call functions inside helper:

```
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

function callFunc<T extends FuncNames>(
    key: T, 
    ...params: Parameters<MyFunctions[T]>): ReturnType<MyFunctions[T]> {
  const func = getFunc(key);
  return func(...params);  // Type error here.
}
```

So I want this to work, but can't archive that. Is it possible with TypeScript?

```
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

const a = callFunc('func1'); // a - string;
const b = callFunc('func2'); // b - number;
const c = callFunc('func3', 'some'); // c - string;
```

By the way, signature of `callFunc` is checked correctly. So compiler successfully check calls from the last example, and enforce params of `callFunc` to be correct, but I can't make an actual call inside this helper. So if I do something like `const func: any = getFunc(key);` everything outside will be still typesafe, but using `any` always is a bad sign.

Is it possible to make `callFunc` fully type safe?

Comment: inside the implementation of `callFunc()`, `T` is an unspecified generic type parameter, and the compiler is not good at the higher order reasoning needed to see if that is safe or not.  I call this problem [correlated records/types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the only reasonable way forward for now is just a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).

Comment: I'm going to close this as a duplicate.  Translating that answer to your question yields [this code](https://tsplay.dev/Qmbv2m).